# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported on the current platform - Install4j on RHEL09

Tags: redhat, install4j, rhel7, rhel9

We are trying to install our application on Red Hat 09 server.
The installer has been created with Install4j 7.0.11.

But the GUI installer gives the following stack trace.

[image]

After this stack trace, the GUI installer runs and executes successfully. But we are worried about this stack trace.

When trying this same installer on Red Hat 07, we are not getting this stack trace.

What could be the reason for this stack trace?

**Update** - After updating the Install4j to the latest version **10.0.6** this stack trace is **not** coming up. Therefore, we would also like to know what has fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of install4j call `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` to check if the Desktop API is supported on the current platform before making the call that failed in your stack trace.